# SEF URLs with .htaccess and mod_rewrite WHEN attributes are missing

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, attributes

My URL structure is:

```
/index.php?lang=en&state=FL&county=Miami-Dade&place=Miami&street=Collins&zip=33140
```

where lang, state, county, place, street and zip are in a hierarchy - lang being the top level - containing all levels below. Looking for a SEF URL like:

```
/en/FL/Miami-Dade/Miami/Collins/33140
```

that I can handle with .htaccess and mod_rewrite when all levels are given in the URL but in my case if I give any URL like

```
/index.php?lang=en&street=Collins&zip=33140
/index.php?zip=33140
/index.php?state=FL&place=Miami&zip=33140
```

it will work perfectly, trying to achieve the same with SEF URLs:

```
/en/Collins/33140
/33140
/FL/Miami/33140
```

in this case the .htaccess will read the SEF url and take the 1st parameter as lang, the 2nd as state and 3rd as county, this will mess up all three examples above (the actual software works with slightly different data, not the ones presented here - cannot use predefined DB).

One solution would be addressing the lang and state parameters separately using ISO codes and read the rest from left to right, assuming that no parameter is skipped, that would always give a positive result. If someone would miss a parameter, no result is generated and can handle the error with PHP.

Anyone ever run into similar situation, any ideas on how to solve this without involving a database of all existing possibilities? Thank you!

Comment: How do you determine in your SEF url what part belongs to what parameter? For a human this might be possible, but for a machine it is impossible to distinguish between `/en/Collins/33140` and `/FL/Miami/33140`. Please reconsider your url format.

Comment: I’d say enforce a URL structure and stick to it. It makes URLs easier to remember and “hackable” (i.e. if I replace “Miami” with “Toronto” in a URL I should get details about Toronto), and also makes your life as a developer easier when it comes to routing requests.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to make a few assumptions about this, because if you *know* that the state is always 2 capital letters, the zip is 5 numbers, the lang is 2 lower case letters, and the city, county, and street is some mix of *both* lower and upper case letters and maybe dashes and periods, then you can try to make some guesses.

The best way to go about it is probably not forcing htaccess to figure this out, it knows something about what's in your database, or what are streets or counties. You could simply use PATH_INFO, and do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^index\.php ^/index.php%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Then use php's `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` to get the request (e.g. `/en/FL/Miami-Dade/Miami/Collins/33140`), explode it, and then try and match which nodes are what.

Another thing you could try doing is adding a prefix or something in front of each node, so something like:

```
/en/FL/c_Miami-Dade/p_Miami/s_Collins/33140
/en/s_Collins/33140
/FL/p_Miami/33140
```

Then you'll be able to differentiate between the "country", "place", and "street".